# Spring - Don't create bean if a primary bean is present

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean, spring-profiles

Is it possible to prevent the creation of a bean of type `A` if it could be generated as a primary bean

**Example:**

I have two configuration classes and have two profiles.

**AppConfig.java:** (The generic configuration class having all beans)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("${host}")
    private String host;

    @Bean
    public A getA() {
        //uses the 'host' value to create an object  of type A
       // Involves database connections
    }
     
    @Bean
    public B getB(A a) {  //Others using bean A. This might come from either getA() or getOtherA()
        ...
    }

}
```

**SpecificConfig.java:** (These beans will be created only if `profile-a` is active)

```
@Configuration
@Profile("profile-a")
public class SpecificConfig{
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public A getOtherA() {
     //return a bean of type A
    }
}
```

Here when `profile-a` is chosen, the bean of type `A` will come from `SpecificConfig.java`. But the problem is when *profile-a* is active the parameter `host` in AppConfig.java is not available and hence *getA* method in AppConfig throws an exception.

Since bean of type A is already there or will be there (I'm not sure of the order of bean creation), I don't want the getA() in AppConfig to be executed.
(when profile-a is active)

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Possible solutions:**

1. Add `@Profile({"!profile-a"})` to the top of *getA* method in *AppConfig*.
2. Add *if* checks to see if host param exists.

   I don't want to do the above two as I would have to change in multiple places.
   (There are a bunch of other beans like `A` and other params like `host`)

Thanks

Let me know if any clarification is required.

Comment: why dont you create a custom annotation

Comment: Initially, I wanted the profile specific beans in a separate file. The profile will handle the events differently. (say, instead of writing to a database, it'll write to disk)

Answer (score 4):

The [Condition annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/package-summary.html) of [Spring Boot auto-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-condition-annotations) is a solution to constrain the bean creation.

- `@ConditionalOnBean` : check specified bean classes and/or names are already contained in the BeanFactory.
- `@ConditionalOnProperty` : check specified properties have a specific value

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class SpecificConfig{
   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnBean(A.class)
   @Primary
   public A getOtherA() {
    //return a bean of type A
   }
}
```